# Repeatedly accessing dicionary key vs storing its value in a temporary variable

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a class whose `__init__()` basically takes a dictionary as input and stores it in an instance variable `self._data`. This dictionary contains some data retrieved from a database.

This same class implements some functionalities as well; the typical method would update one key in the dictionary and then persist the change into the database. Here is an example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
    
    @property
    def my_key(self):
        return self._data["my_key"]

    @my_key.setter
    def my_key(self, new_value):
        self._data["my_key"] = new_value
        database.update(new_data = self._data)  # pseudocode for the db update query
```

The code works properly, but my question is: does acessing `self._data` keys repeatedly somehow affect the performance, compared to for example, saving the key in a different instance variable as follows?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
        self._my_key = self_data["my_key"]
    
    @property
    def my_key(self):
        return self._my_key

    @my_key.setter
    def my_key(self, new_value):
        self._data["my_key"] = new_value
        database.update(new_data = self._data)  # pseudocode for the db update query
        self._my_key = new_value  # this is necessary step to avoid getter method returning the old value
```

Which of these 2 approaches is more efficient and clean? Or maybe there's an even better solution? Consider that a very high number of instances and getter/setter calls are expected to be done simultaneously in a 'multithreaded fashion', so even little differences could have a significant impact on execution time.

Comment: why don't you `timeit` to find out which option is better?

Comment: Good rule is to write clean code and to not do harcore-optimizing, until you do some profiling.  First prove that there is a bottleneck - then optimize it and if necessary convert clean code to less clean, faster alternative. Your code is clean with `_data` and its getters/setters.